# Trying to install Perl-Mysql DBD, mysql_config can't be found

Tags: mysql, database, perl

Here's the output:

```
Ian-MacBook-Pro:DBD-mysql-4.011 ianseyer$ sudo Perl Makefile.PL
Can't exec "mysql_config": No such file or directory at Makefile.PL line 76.

Cannot find the file 'mysql_config'! Your execution PATH doesn't seem 
not contain the path to mysql_config. Resorting to guessed values!
Can't exec "mysql_config": No such file or directory at Makefile.PL line 454.
Can't find mysql_config. Use --mysql_config option to specify where mysql_config is located
Can't exec "mysql_config": No such file or directory at Makefile.PL line 454.
Can't find mysql_config. Use --mysql_config option to specify where mysql_config is located
Can't exec "mysql_config": No such file or directory at Makefile.PL line 454.
Can't find mysql_config. Use --mysql_config option to specify where mysql_config is located


PLEASE NOTE:

For 'make test' to run properly, you must ensure that the 
database user 'root' can connect to your MySQL server 
and has the proper privileges that these tests require such 
as 'drop table', 'create table', 'drop procedure', 'create procedure'
as well as others. 

mysql> grant all privileges on test.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 's3kr1t';

You can also optionally set the user to run 'make test' with:

perl Makefile.pl --testuser=username

Can't exec "mysql_config": No such file or directory at Makefile.PL line 454.
Can't find mysql_config. Use --mysql_config option to specify where mysql_config is located
Can't exec "mysql_config": No such file or directory at Makefile.PL line 454.
Can't find mysql_config. Use --mysql_config option to specify where mysql_config is located
Can't exec "mysql_config": No such file or directory at Makefile.PL line 454.
Can't find mysql_config. Use --mysql_config option to specify where mysql_config is located
Failed to determine directory of mysql.h. Use

  perl Makefile.PL --cflags=-I

to set this directory. For details see the INSTALL.html file,
section "C Compiler flags" or type

  perl Makefile.PL --help
```

I've researched the issue and tried making a symlink to no avail.

Do I have to compile this myself?

Comment: Installing `libmysqlclient-dev` solves the issue in ubuntu.

Answer (score 63):

If you installed the mysql server that everybody installs:
sudo apt-get install mysql-server  (or something like this)

you are missing a few extra files on which the makefile for this perl module depends.

You can try to work around this issue by installing the  following package:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

REFERENCE:
http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RUDY/DBD-mysql-2.9008/INSTALL.html#configuration

Comment: Max OS X equivalent:  [`brew`](http://brew.sh/)[`install mysql`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10855483/3437608)

Comment: ... or sudo apt-get install libmariadbd-dev

Comment: @eli's answer worked for me though I was using a docker container, i couldn't find any package named libmysqlclient-dev

Answer (score 18):

Applying to ubuntu/debian users (I'm running U-12.0.4), it was suggested above that users do:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

But then there is another problem with the maketest portion of the install where the "password: NO" FAILED. To bypass that test, just use force:

```
sudo cpan -f DBD::mysql
```

Comment: I like this answer because there are situations where installing the entire mysql-server package is undesirable.

Answer (score 11):

Install the `mysql-devel` package that pertains to your distro and mysql server version.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Also, please note that if you're using a fork of mysql you have to install the devel package matching that fork and version e.g. `Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-devel-56`.

Comment: At least what it needs with CentOS. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

if u r using ubuntu , u can easily install using the below `cmd`

```
    sudo apt-get install libdbd-mysql-perl
```

for more detail check the cpan [install.pod](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.026/lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod) consist detail about other Linux flavor

Answer (score 4):

Find the script `mysql_config.pl` under your MySQL directory, and run `Makefile.PL` like:

```
perl Makefile.PL --mysql_config=/path/to/mysql-5.x.y.zzz/bin/mysql_config.pl
```

Comment: What do you do if you don;t want mysql installed on the local machine?

Comment: I dunno, maybe go watch TV. `DBD::mysql` depends on the MySQL client libraries.

Answer (score 4):

You just need mysql-server and mysql-devel installed locally so that cpan can build the module, you can probably remove the mysql server afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

If you try to install via CPAN you cannot, as far as I know, set the `--mysql_config` option directly. And, including the directory containing mysql_config in the PATH environment variable does not seem to help.

However, if you do have the file mysql_config available somewhere, you can do the following to make the install succeed:

```
ln -s /path/to/mysql_config /usr/local/bin/
```

Then, remove the symbolic link after the DBD::mysql installation.

The tests during install will still fail, unless you have installed MySQL in some central/default location on your system, but installation will still succeed.

If you do not have mysql_config available, you can get it from a tar.gz download of the MySQL Community Server from [mysql.com](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql). It will be located in the bin/ subdirectory of the extracted files. If you want to have MySQL installed on your system, a better option is probably to download the RPMs and install them, or install via the package management system of your OS.

Answer (score 2):

Try `yum install mariadb-devel` for CentOS 7 and then 
run the required Perl module installation such as `cpan DBD::mysql`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting make test errors. This helped me;

```
perl Makefile.PL  --testuser=bob  --testpass=bobtest
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved installing libmariadbclient-dev, libmariadb-dev and mariadb-client on debian 9.13

```
apt install mariadb-client libmariadbclient-dev libmariadb-dev
```