# missing mysql_config error while installing DBD::mysql

Tags: mysql, perl, dbd

I saw [Trying to install Perl-Mysql DBD, mysql_config can't be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729722/trying-to-install-perl-mysql-dbd-mysql-config-cant-be-found/4729876#4729876), and tried to locate mysql_config, but didn't find it. So, I tried to install mysql-devel, and then I get this error-

```
[nbezzala@stats /]$ sudo yum install mysql-devel  
[sudo] password for nbezzala: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror  
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  
 * base: mirrors.cmich.edu  
 * extras: holmes.umflint.edu  
 * updates: mirror.symnds.com  
Setting up Install Process  
Resolving Dependencies  
--> Running transaction check  
---> Package mysql-devel.i386 0:5.0.77-4.el5_6.6 set to be updated  
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15 for package: mysql-devel  
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.15 for package: mysql-devel  
---> Package mysql-devel.x86_64 0:5.0.77-4.el5_6.6 set to be updated  
--> Running transaction check  
---> Package mysql.i386 0:5.0.77-4.el5_6.6 set to be updated  
--> Processing Conflict: mysql conflicts MySQL  
--> Finished Dependency Resolution  
mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386 from base has depsolving problems  
  --> mysql conflicts with MySQL-server  
Error: mysql conflicts with MySQL-server  
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems  
                        package-cleanup --dupes  
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest  
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.  
[nbezzala@stats /]$
```

Comment: You can install DBD-mysql with yum, but it would be an older version. "yum install perl-DBD-mysql". Which distribution do you use?

Comment: Did you install mysql from package that is not for you Linux distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql v 5.5.17 was installed on the machine, and I was trying to install 5.0.77 components via yum. Thanks Alexandr.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and had to install **libmysqlclient-dev** on my Debian linux. 
That `mysql_config` file was in that package.